# Can someone explain where Applicative instances arise in this code?

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative

```
isAlphaNum :: Char -> Bool
isAlphaNum = (||) <$> isAlpha <*> isNum
```

I can see that it works, but I don't understand where the instances of `Applicative` (or `Functor`) come from.

Comment: `isAlphaNum` == `(\c-> ((||).isAlpha) c (isNum c))` == `(\c-> isAlpha c || isNum c)` (... just a sidenote).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is the `Applicative` instance for `((->) r)`, functions from a common type. It combines functions with the same first argument type into a single function by duplicating a single argument to use for all of them. `(<$>)` is function composition, pure is `const`, and here's what `(<*>)` translates to:

```
s :: (r -> a -> b) -> (r -> a) -> r -> b
s f g x = f x (g x)
```

This function is perhaps better known as [the S combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic).

The `((->) r)` functor is also the `Reader` monad, where the shared argument is the "environment" value, e.g.:

```
newtype Reader r a = Reader (r -> a)
```

I wouldn't say it's *common* to do this for the sake of making functions point-free, but in some cases it can actually improve clarity once you're used to the idiom. The example you gave, for instance, I can read very easily as meaning "is a character a letter or number".

Answer (score 7):

You get instances of what are called static arrows (see "Applicative Programming with Effects" by Conor McBride et al.) for free from the `Control.Applicative` package. So, any source type, in your case `Char`, gives rise to an Applicative instance where any other type `a` is mapped to the type `Char -> a`.

When you combine any of these, say apply a function `f :: Char -> a -> b` to a value `x :: Char -> a`, the semantic is that you create a new function `Char -> b`, which will feed its argument into both `f` and `x` like so,

```
f <*> x = \c -> (f c) (x c)
```

Hence, as you point out, this makes your example equivalent to

```
isAlphaNum c = (isAlpha c) || (isNum c)
```

In my opinion, such effort is not always necessary, and it would look nicer if Haskell had better syntactic support for applicatives (maybe something like 2-level languages).

Answer (score 3):

It should be noted that you get a similar effect by using the lift functions, e.g.:

```
import Data.Char
import Control.Applicative 

isAlphaNum = liftA2 (||) isAlpha isNumber
```

Or, using the monad instance of ((->) r) instead of the applicative one:

```
import Data.Char
import Control.Monad 

isAlphaNum = liftM2 (||) isAlpha isNumber
```

**[Digression]**

Now that you know how to distribute *one* argument to *two* intermediate functions and the result to a binary function, there is the somehow related case that you want to distribute *two* arguments to *one* intermediate function and the results to a binary function:

```
import Data.Function

orFst = (||) `on` fst

-- orFst (True,3) (False, 7)
--> True
```

This pattern is e.g. often used for the `compare` function.

Comment: There is also `Control.Concatenative` which brings some standard concatenative combinators into Haskell. Your examples could just as well be `bi isAlpha isNumber (||)` and `fst \`biAp\` (||)`. It doesn’t necessarily show here, but `Control.Concatenative` does help improve legibility for a lot of point-free expressions, because, well, that’s what concatenative programming is all about.